# How do I know which PEEZ dispensers I've collected?

Tags: kingdom-of-loathing

Every time I use a PEEZ dispenser, it tells me which one it is and I mark it off on my checklist before I throw it away.

Is there an actual checklist for these somewhere, where I can see which ones I've collected? Or is this just throwaway flavour text?

Answer (score 3):

You can bring up the checklist by clicking any PEEZ dispenser you have in your inventory. The checklist is displayed in the info popup.

You can also view the popup [directly](http://www.kingdomofloathing.com/desc_item.php?whichitem=168804605) if you don't have one in your inventory.

Comment: So if I have used them all, I can't see it until I have another one?

Comment: Searching the mall for PEEZ dispensers ought to work too, you can view item descriptions from there.

Comment: @AshleyNunn Just use the link in my answer to load the popup!